# R Using JavaScript to customize DT tables

Tags: javascript, r, dt

I have previously asked how to colour cells based on colours stored in hidden columns ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105725/dt-apply-background-colour-to-cell-based-on-separate-data-frame)) and how to get information when hovering a cell ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155336/dt-cell-hover-showing-cell-based-sample-sizes-from-hidden-column)). I would also like to do some formatting at the same time.

I want to expand my initial posts where I want to:

1. Add colour depending on colour specified in the data frame
2. Add the hover option to display the sample sizes related to the individual cells (also in the data frame).
3. Apply number formatting to specified columns

Example data:

```
dat <- iris[1:5,1:5]
colours2apply <- sample(x=c(rgb(1, 0, 0 ), rgb(1, 1, 0 ), rgb(0, 1, 1 )), 25, replace = T) %>% 
  matrix(nrow=5) %>% 
  data.frame()
set.seed(1234)
SampleSizesToShowInHover <- matrix(round(runif(n = 25, 10, 1000)), nrow=5)

  dat <- cbind(dat, colours2apply)
  dat <- cbind(dat, SampleSizesToShowInHover)
dat
```

The final solution to do 1 and 2 at the same time is:

```
library(DT)
solution12 <- DT::datatable(dat, 
                options = 
                  list(
                    columnDefs = list(
                      list(
                        visible=FALSE, 
                        targets = 6:15
                      )
                    ), 
                    rowCallback = JS(
                      "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
                      'for(i=0; i<5; i++ ){',
                      "var full_text = 'n = '+ aData[i+10];",
                      "$('td:eq('+i+')', nRow).attr('title', full_text).css('background-color', aData[i+5]);",
                      '}',
                      "}")
                    
                    
                  )
)
solution12
```

How would I integrate JavaScript in order to present the data in columns 3 and 4 as percentages with 1 decimal place, while keeping the solutions to 1 and 2?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add percentage sign with single digit round off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the number to percentage we could just multiply the number by 100. To round it to 1 decimal place we can use js function `toFixed(1)` and then we can just add the percentage sign using `+ %`. To preserve your initial formatting and add the new changes it would be as follows:
 `"$('td:eq('+i+')', nRow).attr('title', full_text).css('background-color', aData[i+5]).html((aData[i]*100).toFixed(1)+ '%');",`

The change in code to just add this to column 3 and 4 would be as follows:

```
  DT::datatable(dat, 
                            options = 
                              list(
                                columnDefs = list(
                                  list(
                                    visible=FALSE, 
                                    targets = 6:15
                                  )
                                ), 
                                rowCallback = JS(
                                  "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
                                  'for(i=0; i<5; i++ ){',
                                  "var full_text = 'n = '+ aData[i+10];",
                                 "if(i === 3 || i=== 4) {",
                                 "$('td:eq('+i+')', nRow).attr('title', full_text).css('background-color', aData[i+5]).html((aData[i]*100).toFixed(1)+ '%');",
                                 "}",
                                 "else{",
                                 "$('td:eq('+i+')', nRow).attr('title', full_text).css('background-color', aData[i+5]);",
                                 "}",
                                  '}',
                                  "}")
                              )
)
```

With this change the output you get is:
[image]